# How to allow users in ACL group to add & remove contacts in groups

Tags: groups, acl

I'm implementing ACLs for a client.  Users can only have view or edit to a group when adding permissions, so then don't have the ability to add or remove a contact from that group. In fact, I've found there are ways to add and delete a contact to/from a group - but the more usual methods result in the message *"API permission check failed for GroupContact/delete call; insufficient permission: require access CiviCRM and edit all contacts*"

 This is a Drupal system & they have 'edit groups' permissions. Giving the permission 'edit all contacts' then opens up all contacts to a user, which is obviously incorrect.

Is this a limitation of ACLs? Or is there some way around this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try apply [patch](https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/14339.patch) from here ? If the patch works for you than it would be worth adding your test result on [PR](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/14339) to speed up the merge process.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't do cmd line stuff, I'm strictly an implementer. Actually I do cmd line stuff on IBM mainframes but that was many years ago! If you can send me the full code I can install that, rather than the patch. And thx for the fast response.

Comment: You can also apply the patch manually by editing the file and adding lines with says + and remove lines which says -